# Heroku takes Play subproject as main

Tags: heroku, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a Play 2.3 application consisting of a root with 2 subprojects. When running locally everything is fine.

When I deploy the application to Heroku, it assumes wrongly that one of my subprojects is the main one so I am able to access only routes for this subproject.

I read something about alphabetical ordering so I took care of renaming my projects `root`, `rootAdmin` and `rootCommon` but this did not help much.

Is there any way to tell Heroku which one is the real "main" project? Maybe through `build.sbt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did not have anything to do with Heroku. The problem turned out to be an entry in my subproject's application.conf:

`application.router=rootadmin.Routes`

Somehow my subproject's application.conf was read after the main application.conf and the entry above took precedence - so this is why only the routes from the subproject were accessible.

I had added the above line with the idea to be able to develop my subproject as a standalone application - so I needed to somehow run it. Now I see that I skipped a part of the documentation which mentions this use case:

> To use a specific set of settings in development mode for a sub project, it would be even better to put these settings into the build file, e.g. Keys.devSettings += ("application.router", "admin.Routes").

This means that this line is now part of my `build.sbt` and does not need to reside in the `application.conf`